# Si può chiamare "allarmista" un riparatore di sistemi di allarme?

Tags: vocabulary

Se, per esempio, un riparatore di impianti elettrici può essere chiamato elettricista o un lavoratore del marmo può essere chiamato marmista, può allora un riparatore di sistemi di allarme essere chiamato allarmista?

Answer (score 6):

Come sappiamo "allarmista" è «chi va spargendo notizie che destano allarme o apprensione» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/allarmista/)), così come un "catastrofista" è «chi […] prevede sempre catastrofi e tende a fare previsioni pessimistiche della realtà» ([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/catastrofista/)).

Con un po' di fantasia si potrebbe chiamare "allarmista" chi installa/ripara sistemi/impianti di allarme e "catastrofista" chi gestisce emergenze e catastrofi naturali, perché no?

Ma la domanda è: gli elettricisti che installano/riparano sistemi/impianti di allarme chiamano sé stessi "allarmisti", magari con un pizzico di ironia?

Secondo me no, come suggerito ad esempio da [questa ricerca](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b5bRU8GxBcvC8gfsv4CwAg&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22allarmista%22+site:http:%2F%2Fwww.paginegialle.it&safe=active) da cui si evince che nelle Pagine Gialle italiane c'è un solo allarmista in tutta Italia, a Pescara, evidentemente quello con il maggior senso dell'umorismo. Cercando invece "[sistemi di allarme](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b5bRU8GxBcvC8gfsv4CwAg&gws_rd=cr#q=%22sistemi+di+allarme%22+site:http:%2F%2Fwww.paginegialle.it&safe=active)" o "[impianti di allarme](https://www.google.it/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=b5bRU8GxBcvC8gfsv4CwAg&gws_rd=cr#q=%22impianti+di+allarme%22+site:http:%2F%2Fwww.paginegialle.it&safe=active)", la ricerca dà ben altri risultati.

Quindi la risposta è sì, in astratto si potrebbe anche dire; ma, allo stato attuale, in italiano corrente, non si dice, sempre a meno che la tua intenzione non sia principalmente umoristica.

Comment: Dopo aver visto decine di porte quasi terrorizzate (perché *allarmate*) non mi stupirei più di niente. `;-)`